# Rider (2022.2.4, .NET 6.0.6) on MacOs: how to enable Hot Reload option for debuggin

Tags: .net, macos, rider, hot-reload, jetbrains-rider

How to enable Hot Reload in Rider on MacOs?

Did anyone succeeded with this on practice?

I was looking for pluggin for this purpose, but there aren't any; as well - looked for this option in Preferences - it is said that it's available for Windows only [image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limitations of the .NET Hot Reload for debugging, it is indeed available on the Windows Operating System only. You may want to subscribe to our issue with the ID [RIDER-31366](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-31366/Hot-Reload-Debug-support-for-non-Windows-OS). Eiter upvote it or press the **Watch Issue** button to receive notifications about the issue's progress.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-31366/Hot-Reload-Debug-support-for-non-Windows-OS

Comment: Wait for dotnet 8

Comment: @CodeNameJack why dotnet8 . What will br changed ?